# Can I somehow filter the error message lines from GCC?

Tags: c++, bash, debugging, gcc, clipboard

While coding in C++, I often get a really long error message for simple errors, such as mismatched parameters in function calls or parameter ambiguity. These error messages usually span through tens even hundreds of lines, and it is pretty difficult to find where the actual error is.

Is it possible to do some manipulation on the output to find the error location "lazily"?

I'm looking for something like:

```
make |& xclip_error_loc
... (make output)
(prints and/or adds this to the clipboard: sourcefile.cc:86:2)
```

It would be a really useful debugging tool. How do I achieve this?

Example compilation error:

```
Compiling test: "createClusterSizePairFrequencyValidationPlots"...
src/createClusterSizePairFrequencyValidationPlots.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
src/createClusterSizePairFrequencyValidationPlots.cc:167:62: error: no matching function for call to 'TH2I::Fill(const int&, const float&, const char [2])'
 ngthYVsPhi_H  .Fill(cluster.sizeY,       phi, "1");
                                                  ^
In file included from /cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2D.h:25:0,
                 from src/../interface/ClusterPairFunctions.h:7,
                 from src/createClusterSizePairFrequencyValidationPlots.cc:8:
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:63:13: note: candidate: virtual Int_t TH2::Fill(Double_t)
    Int_t    Fill(Double_t); //MayNotUse
             ^
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:63:13: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:64:13: note: candidate: virtual Int_t TH2::Fill(const char*, Double_t)
    Int_t    Fill(const char*, Double_t) { return Fi
             ^
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:64:13: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:75:21: note: candidate: virtual Int_t TH2::Fill(Double_t, Double_t)
    virtual Int_t    Fill(Double_t x, Double_t y);
                     ^
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:75:21: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:76:21: note: candidate: virtual Int_t TH2::Fill(Double_t, Double_t, Double_t)
    virtual Int_t    Fill(Double_t x, Double_t y, Do
                     ^
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:76:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from 'const char [2]' to 'Double_t {aka double}'
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:77:21: note: candidate: virtual Int_t TH2::Fill(Double_t, const char*, Double_t)
    virtual Int_t    Fill(Double_t x, const char *na
                     ^
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:77:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const float' to 'const char*'
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:78:21: note: candidate: virtual Int_t TH2::Fill(const char*, Double_t, Double_t)
    virtual Int_t    Fill(const char *namex, Double_
                     ^
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:78:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from 'const char [2]' to 'Double_t {aka double}'
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_8_0_18/external/slc6_amd64_gcc530/bin/../../../../../../lcg/root/6.06.00-ikhhed4/include/TH2.h:79:21: note: candidate: virtual Int_t TH2::Fill(const char*, const char*, Double_t)
    virtual Int_t    Fill(const char *namex, const c
                     ^
(lots of similar lines...)
```

It should output:

createClusterSizePairFrequencyValidationPlots.cc:167:62

**Update to the answer of NIoSaT:**

To copy the error message:

```
make 2>&1 | egrep -o ":[0-9]+:[0-9]+: error" | xargs echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard && xclip -selection clipboard -o && echo ""
```

To copy and display only the first error:

```
make 2>&1 | egrep -o ":[0-9]+:[0-9]+: error" | head -n 1 | xargs echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard && xclip -selection clipboard -o && echo ""
```

Comment: when you are using a *NIX system, you could always pipe it to grep and search for what you want to know

Comment: but can you tell me what should I try to grep to get error locations?

Comment: try something like:
"make 2>&1 | grep line"       to get the line numbers
or grep for "error" if you want to know the error codes

Comment: @NIoSaT What error codes? I'm talking about the gcc compiler (or alternatives). My question is how I should grep (if I even should do that directly) the error locations.

Comment: well when the gcc throws around the error messages there are lines like " error 1 unknown function myfunc() in line 34" or something similar, so you can grep for "error" to find the output lines with the error number in them or you can grep for "line" to find the output lines with the line number in them

Comment: @NIoSaT I'll add an example compiler output, can you tell me what to grep for?

Comment: I hope so but I guess I can give you an exact command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can use grep.

The command would be like this

```
make 2>&1 | egrep ":[0-9]+:[0-9]+: error:"
```

This does two Things

1. It moves stderr to stdout
2. It looks  for :"any number here":"any number": error: and prints out the corresponding line

So you should get only the lines with the information you want

**Update to the answer :**

To copy the error msg:

```
make 2>&1 | egrep -o ":[0-9]+:[0-9]+: error" | xargs echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard && xclip -selection clipboard -o && echo ""
```

To copy and display only the first error:

```
make 2>&1 | egrep -o ":[0-9]+:[0-9]+: error" | head -n 1 | xargs echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard && xclip -selection clipboard -o && echo ""
```

Comment: can you make it only print the filename and the line/col number for the error (no msg)?

Comment: Found the solution:
make 2>&1 | egrep ":[0-9]+:[0-9]+: error" | cut -d : -f1,2,3 | xargs echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard && xclip -selection clipboard -o && echo ""

Comment: there is a simpler solution without the "cut" look at my edited post, and then you can add your clipboard stuff